# Python - same GDAL command giving different results

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdalwarp, osgeo

I've been using GDAL warp to re-project a tiff I have.

On the GDAL commandline I use `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 C:/test/test_file.tif C:/test/test_file_gdal.tif`

Similarly, I wanted to run this function in python, so tried this

```
import os

command = 'gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 C:/test/test_file.tif C:/test/test_file_python.tif'

os.system(command)
```

However, despite them being the exact same command I'm getting 2 differently placed outputs. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Do you use the same GDAL version in both cases?

Comment: @user30184 yeah I am using GDAL version 3.4.0 in both instances